# use to import dta doesn't work for the file in folder?

Tags: stata

I just did

```
use "data.dta"
```

My do file and dta are in the same folder. But it shows me error.

I also tried

```
use "datafolder/data.dta"
```

after placing `data.dta` into that folder. But this doesn't work either.

What should I write? It is not a good idea to write like

```
use "D://... /... /data.dta"
```

because other people should be able to run this code on his computer.

Comment: The error report here is "error" "doesn't work either". This is equivalent to "My car doesn't work". The `.dta` file read in must be in the current directory (type `pwd` to see what that is). Otherwise you must tell `use` where it is on your computer. NB spelling is Stata. not STATA.

Answer (score 0):

Before read the dta file, we need to tell Stata the current directory. Usually we can use `cd` command to change the current working directory. For example, if the `data.dta` is under the "C:\temp" folder, then use the following code:

```
cd "C:\temp"  
use "data.dta"
```

Comment: Strictly there is no need at all to tell Stata the current directory (opening sentence) or to `cd` to the directory containing the file (your code). If that were so no datasets could be read over the internet, for example. Stata just needs to know where the dataset file is to be found.